# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when rdd.saveAsTextFile by spark-shell

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

`parallelize` integers and trying to save as text file like below :

```
scala> val test = sc.parallelize(List(12,2,3,4))
test: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24
```

save as text file

```
 scala> test.saveAsTextFile("/test")
```

Error stack trace like below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskID.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskType;I)V
  at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.setIDs(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.preSetup(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1195)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1071)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1488)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1467)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1467)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1467)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: did you try `test.saveAsTextFile("file:///test")`?

Comment: yes, the same error

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error because `test.saveAsTextFile("/test")` is going to write to hdfs and `test.saveAsTextFile("file:///test")` is going to write to local file system. How can you have hadoop error for the later one?

Comment: Now I know that there is something wrong with my spark environment.

Comment: great to hear that you identified the wrong :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the complete path where you want to save it:

```
test.saveAsTextFile("/home/anurag/test")
```

When you use `test.saveAsTextFile("/test")`, it try to create folder on root directry.

Comment: @SmallWong, is this work for you? please verify it and accept this, if it works .

Comment: No, i have tried serval different path where i want to save, but it does not work.